# Configuration of duplicate-finder-maven-plugin to scan only specific location and excluding everything else

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

Is there a way to configure [Maven duplicate-finder-maven-plugin plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin) to scan only specific location and excluding everything else? Because in this moment, the results shows myriads of conflict that come from project dependencies.

From the [configuration](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin), it looks that the way to do it is explicitly excluding every dependency I don't want to scan.

**Question**: Is there a better practice? How to scan - for example - only the code that is under my direct responsibility, like `com.my-company.my-project`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://github.com/basepom/duplicate-finder-maven-plugin/wiki/Ignoring%20Dependencies%20and%20Resources) your case is already documented as following:

> Ignore all classes that aren't from my company:
>
> ```
>    <configuration>
>         <ignoredClassPatterns>
>             <ignoredClassPattern>^((?!com[/.]mycompany).*)$</ignoredClassPattern>
>         </ignoredClassPatterns>
>     </configuration>
> ```

Note that the configuration option above is only available from plugin version **1.2.1** and later.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, somehow missed it in the doc. Thanks!